# What are these two methods by which a web server handles a HTTP request?

Tags: http

From https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

> A web server can handle a Hypertext Transfer Protocol request either
>   by reading a file from its file system based on the URL path or by
>   handling the request using logic that is specific to the type of
>   resource. In cases where special logic is invoked, the query string
>   will be available to that logic for use in its processing, along with
>   the path component of the URL.

What does the quote mean by the two methods by which a web server can handle a HTTP request

- "by reading a file from its file system based on the URL path"
- "by handling the request using logic that is specific to the type of resource"?

Can you give specific examples to explain the two methods?

Is the query string   used in both method?

Thanks.

Comment: It just means on many websites (like this one, for example) there's no actual `questions/42217275/what-are-these-two-methods-by-which-a-web-server-handles-a-http-request.html` file created when you created this question - there's one file (or set of files) that's looking in the database and retrieving your question for display based off an ID or URL or whatnot.

Answer (score 1):

> by reading a file from its file system based on the URL path

^ The web site uses a generic mapping mechanism to convert a URL path to a local filesystem path, and then returns the file located at that path.  This is common with static files like .css.

> by handling the request using logic that is specific to the type of resource"

^ The web site turns control over to a web application, which contains code written by a developer.  The code reads the query string and decides what to do.  The logic for deciding what to do is completely customizable, and there does not need to be a static file in the local filesystem that matches the URL.